# Create table in MySQL with a constraint to prevent associating value of a column with different values of another column

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a new table in MySQL. The table should hold details about the existing hardware which can be a laptop, printer, scanner, etc. The details include, the hardware_id, hardware_type, name, and if it is in_use.

Example of the table:

```
+----+------------+---------------+----------------------+
| id |hardware_id | hardware_type |accessories | in_use  |
+----+------------+---------------+----------------------+
| 1  |hw1         | laptop        | charger    | true    |
| 2  |hw1         | laptop        | mouse      | false   |
| 3  |hw2         | scanner       |            | false   |
| 4  |hw3         | cell phone    | charger    | true    |
| 5  |hw3         | cell phone    | headset    | true    |
+----+------------+---------------+-----------------------+
```

I would like to create the table using MySQL with the constraint to prevent using the same `hardware_id` for different `hardware_type`. In other words, the same `hardware_id` has to be always associated with the same `hardware_type`.

Even if multiple records with different accessories exist for the same `hardware_id` in the table, then that `hardware_id` is
always associated to the same `hardware_type`.

I would like to prevent the scenario below where the same `hardware_id` hw1 for example is wrongly associated with two different `hardware_type` laptop and scanner.

```
+----+------------+---------------+----------------------+
| id |hardware_id | hardware_type |accessories | in_use  |
+----+------------+---------------+----------------------+
| 1  |hw1         | laptop        | charger    | true    |
| 2  |hw1         | scanner       |            | false   |
| 3  |hw2         | scanner       |            | false   |
| 4  |hw3         | cell phone    | charger    | true    |
| 5  |hw3         | cell phone    | headset    | true    |
+----+------------+---------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a constraint, since it's not allowed to perform queries. You could do it with a trigger that signals an error if the check fails.

Comment: Why don't you just make `hardware_id` a unique column? If it has attributes that can have multiple values, put that in another table with a foreign key.

Comment: You must put *hardware_type* in an other table: your table - let's call it *hardware_details* - will contains only *hardware_id* and *in_use* fields, table hardware_types will contains *id* as unique or better as autoincrement and also *hardware_type*, then you need to add a contstraint on *hardware_id* of *hardware_details* to enable only the ids of table *hardware_type*

Comment: Normalizing the structure will solve your problem easily.